# An Hardy-Littlewood like inequality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, integral-inequality

Let $\mu$ be a finite Borel measure on $R$. Show that $|\{x\in R : \sup_{r>0} \frac{1}{2r} \mu ([x-r,x+r]) \ge \lambda \}| \le \frac{C}{\lambda} \mu(R)$ for any $\lambda > 0$ and some absolute constant $C > 0$.

Get stuck with this one. Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: You know it is true if $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, because that is just Hardy-Littlewood for $L^1$ functions.  So I think you are somehow supposed to use the fact that $L^1$ is weakly dense in the space of finite Borel measures.  But it is too late at night, and I cannot figure it out right now.

Answer (score 1):

I assume $\mu$ is a non-negative measure.  If $\mu = f(x) \, dx$ for some $f \in L^1$ (i.e. if $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure), then we know it to be true by Hardy-Littlewood.  Now replace the left hand side by
$$ |\{x\in\mathbb R:r^{-1} \int \phi(r^{-1}x) \, d\mu(x)>\lambda\}| $$
 where $\phi:\mathbb R \to [0,1]$ is such that $\phi(x) = 1$ if $|x|\le 1$, and $\phi(x) = 0$ if $|x|\ge 2$, and $\phi$ is continuous.  Note that
$$ |\{x\in\mathbb R:r^{-1} \int \phi(r^{-1}x) \, d\mu(x)>\lambda\}| \le 2C \mu(\mathbb R) $$
if $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Now if $\mu$ is any finite, Borel measure, take a sequence of measures $\mu_n$ that are absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, such that $\mu_n$ converges weakly to $\mu$, remembering that the space of measures is the dual of $C_0(\mathbb R)$, and then maybe use the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem on the left hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chebychev inequality ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality#Statement)) and the fact that since $\mu$ is finite, it must be radon, and there exists a distribution function $F$ corresponding to $\mu$.